# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable and getting more error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I keep getting the error and I don't know what to do

'''

```
def Types_of_integer(*num):
    num = list(num)
    num = num.sort()
    num = set(num)
    for i in num:
        if (i&2) ==0 :
            print("{} : Prime number".format(i))
        else:
            print("{} : Composite Number".format(i))

Types_of_integer(10,9,22,32,45,9,2,103,71,45)
Types_of_integer(49,37,14,37)
```

'''

Comment: `num = num.sort()` Check the docs -- `.sort()` is inplace so it returns None. If you get an error like this, try printing your variable on the line above the error. The fix is remove `num = ` on the `sort` call.